# How to open a dropbox file in the application webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropbox

I have a [link from dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bj70bnggflp2f08/Getting%20Started.pdf?dl=0). This link has a pdf file which I need to open in my application webpage.

Now I need to show this pdf file in my application webpage.

I tried to load this pdf in my webpage using **iframe** tag. But I get the following error
**cannot load the pdf file because x-frame options is set to SAMEORIGIN**

If I use anchor tag, it redirects to dropbox.com page. But I want to open this pdf file in my application webpage.

Using the URL link above, How can I open a pdf file, stored in dropbox, in my application webpage?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few potential solutions to this issue...

1: Dropbox's answer is to change the share URL as follows (adding '?raw=1' at the end):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmocfrco2t0d28o/Fluffbeast.docx?raw=1

Reference: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/201

In my experience with an enterprise iPad app download link to an .ipa file that required SSL, Solution #1 doesn't work as well for connections that require SSL (most likely due to a redirect).

2: An alternative solution did the trick, though... format the URL as one of the following:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/USERID/FOLDER/FILE?raw=1
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/USERID/FOLDER/FILE?dl=1

Working examples:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100618/dropbox-get-link-screenshot.png?raw=1
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100618/dropbox-get-link-screenshot.png?dl=1

More info:

http://www.skyleet.net/2014/11/how-to-get-direct-download-link-from.html

Comment: The redirect is to another HTTPS URL, so I don't see why SSL would be an issue.

Comment: Good tip with the `?raw=1`. For your second tip, I don't think it's working the way you think it is. I'm guessing your "working example" files are in a "Public" Dropbox folder, which get handled a bit differently than standard Dropbox files. Notice that even without the `?raw=1`, the file is shown directly. For files not in the Public folder, changing the URL to include  `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` will allow for downloading, but not displaying. OP specifically wants to display the PDF, so this is relevant. Also, Dropbox accounts created after July 31st, 2012 do not have a Public folder.

Comment: Here's a sample that uses the raw=1 solution to embed a PDF onto an HTML page in an iframe. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ew7xv41srpmwyxa/iframe_pdf_test.html (The HTML page itself also happens to be hosted on Dropbox, but that's not important.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Adding ?raw=1 worked for pdf file. But if I try to display pptx file or doc file in my browser webpage using ?raw=1, it is downloading the file and not displaying on the same webpage.